# Extreme values $f(x)=(x-2)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: calculus, extreme-value-theorem

find all points of intrest for the function:

$f(x)=(x-2)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Here we can clearly see that when $x=2$  $f(x)=0$ so I know that there atleast should exist a critical point.

Since the function is when taking it's derivative

I get

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{3(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$

I know that this is an odd function therefor it will be symmetric about the origin and will alwaays be increasing. However accoriding to the formula there are no max or min values.

Which confuses me since singular points are found where the derivative is undefined i.e at $x=2$ so why is't the function either a max/min at $x=2$?

Many thanks to whomever might help me with this!

Answer (score 2):

Max and min occure  when a derivative $f'(x)$ is equal to $0$.  If the derivative is undefined then.... it is not equal to $0$.

If we think of the derivative as the "slope" of the tangent line of the function at a point $x$ then $f'(x)$ being undefined means the slope is infinite at that point. .... which is precise what happens and $x = 2$.  Then function $f$ is at that instant increasing at an infinite rate.

(It only has infinite increasing at a single infinitisimal point so that is quite possible.)

....

> Here we can clearly see that when $x=2$ $f(x)=0$ so I know that there atleast should exist a critical point.

That's not a critical point.  That is an $x$-intercept.  It's point of interest because ... it is a point where the graph intercepts that $x$ axis, that other than that it doesn't say anything else.  It is not a critical point.

The other point of inters would be the $y$-intercept, where $x = 0$ and $f(x) = -(\frac 12)^{\frac 13}$.  That is where the graph intercepts the $y$ axis.  It is also not a critical point.

> I know that this is an odd function therefor it will be symmetric about the origin

It is not an odd function $f(-x)=(-x-2)^{\frac{1}{3}}\ne -(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}}=-f'(x)$.  So it is not odd.

It is symmetric around the $x = 2$ line.

> and will alwaays be increasing.

It'll be always increasing if $f'(x) > 0$ always.

Which in this case $f'(x) = \frac{1}{3(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}}} = \frac 1{3\sqrt[3]{(x -2)^2}} > 0$ so $f$ is always increasing.

> However accoriding to the formula there are no max or min values.

That's to be expected.

If something is *always* increasing (or decreasing) it *can't* have a max or a min.

To have a minimum the (continuous) function must decrease to a lowest point... and then stop decreasing and start *in*creasing.  Likewise to have a maximum the function must increase to a maximum.  Stop increasing.  And then decrease.

---

Here the image:

[image]

As you can see the function *not* symetric at the $y$-axis so it is not even nor is rotational around the origin so it is not odd.  It is rotation around the $(2,0)$ point so it is "odd-like".

Now look at the point $(2,0)$.  See how the function is going *straight up and down*.  That is because the derivative $f'(x)=\frac{1}{3(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$ is undefined at $x=2$ and would evaluate to $\frac 10$ which is undefined.  The function's tangent line *has infinite slope*.  **It goes straight up and down**.

Now, notice there is no way any sane person using basic english language could call that a minimum (It gets immediately smaller when $x < 2$), or maximum (It gets immediately larger at $x > 2$), nor a saddle-point (you can't sit on it-- you'd fall off).  I suppose we could call it a stripper-pole point but... well, thank goodness we don't.

Now in response to a comment here we have the function $g(x) = (x-2)^{\frac 23}x$.

Where $g(A) > g(c)$ and $g(B) > g(c)$ and $A < c < B$.

[image]

But notice $c$ is not the *only* such point that is true of nearly *all* the points between $A$ and $B$.

It has $g'(x) =\frac{1}{3(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}}}x + (x-2)^{\frac 13}$

$g'(2)$ is still undefined and we still have "stripper-pole" point at $(2,0)$.

But at $x = 1 \frac 23$ we have $g'(x) = 0$.  And at that point, a *different* point, we have a critical point. A minimum.

So $x < 1\frac 23$ we see $g'(x)< 0$ and $g$ is decreasing.

At $x = 1\frac 23$ we see $g'(x) = 0$ and we have "flatline".  We've hit bottom.  It's a local (and as it turns out global) minimum.

At $x > 1\frac 23$ we see $g'(x) > 0$ and the $g$ it increases.  ... very fast.

At $x = 2$ it is increasing infinitely fast and the graph is straight up and down.  $g'(2)$ is undefined and we have a "stripper-pole" point.  These points, are increasing or decreasing infinitely fast so that can only exist at a single point.

At $x > 2$ we so that $g'(x) > 0$ and the function is still increasing, but not as fast.  It hit a maximum rate of increase at $x = 2$.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. But are you saying that singular points cannot be the absolut maxima/minma for a function?

Comment: Singular points of the function?  Or singular points of the *derivative* of a function?  It depends on the type of singularity.  If its a "the denominator  equals zero" singularity of the derivative than no, that will not be a max or min.

Comment: A singular point "c" on a interval where  "a" and "b" are the endpoints for a function. If f(a) > f(c) and f(b) > f(c) would't this mean that the point "c" is either a local minmum or absolut minimum, even though the derivative for po "c" is undefined?  Thank you btw

Comment: *IF* (and it's a big if) the function is continuous everywhere, then if $a < c < b$ and $f(a) > f(c)$ and $f(b) > f(c)$ then i) at some but not nescessarily all points between $a$ and $c$ the derivative is negative and the function is decreasing, ii) at some but not necessarily all points between $c$ and $b$ the derivative is positive and the function is increasing.  iii) At some point between $a$ and $b$ but not necessarily at $c$ there is a local minimum and the derivative is $0$.

Comment: ....  Meanwhile we know *nothing* about $c$ itself.  It's derivative could be positive meaning the function is increasing and a local minimum is somewhere between a and c.  It's derivative could be negative meaning the function is decreasing a local minimum is somewhere between c and a.  The derivative could be 0 meaning it is a critical point (max/min/saddle) but there might be others.  Or the derivative could be infinite in which case it is *definitely NOT* a critical point (max/min/saddle).

Comment: Look..   Just DRAW some pictures.  To be a minimum at x= c the function must be going down for $x < c$ and going up for $x> c$ and flatlining at $x=c$.  So $f'(x) < 0$ for $x < c$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for $x > c$ and $f'(c) = 0$.  If $f(c) = \frac 10$ then the function at that point is going *straight up and down*; it isn't flat.  It can not be a max nor a min.

Answer (score 1):

First, you said

> Here we can clearly see that when $x=2$ $f(x)=0$ so I know that there at least should exist a critical point.

This is **not** a criteria for a critical point. A critical point occurs when $f'(x) = 0$

Second, you said

> I know that this is an odd function

$f'(x)$ not **not** an odd function. You can tell just from the fact that it's only defined on $(2,\infty)$. The definition of an odd function is $f(-x) = -f(x)$. $x=0$ isn't anywhere in the domain, so $f(-x)$ doesn't even make any sense.

The reason we're considering $x=2$ is because it's on the boundary of the function's domain, which is $[2,\infty)$. Because $f'(x) > 0, \forall x > 2$ , $f(x)$ is increasing on the interval $(2,\infty)$. This makes $x=2$ a minimum of the function.

Singular points in the derivative have nothing to do with the function's max/min.

---

**Addendum:**

> I know that this is an odd function therefor it will be symmetric about the origin and will always be increasing.

If we're being generous and interpret the function as $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x-2}$, which is defined for $x < 2$, this still wouldn't make $f(x)$ an odd function. You can say that it's anti-symmetric about the point $x=2$ since $\sqrt[3]{2-x} = -\sqrt[3]{x-2}$.

Comment: `it's only defined on (2,∞)` Not so, $\,f\,$ is defined on $\,\mathbb{R}\,$, and $\,f'\,$ is defined on $\,\mathbb{R} \setminus \{2\}\,$

Comment: @dxiv Functions of the form $x^\alpha$ are only defined for $x \ge 0$. $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is defined on $\Bbb R$, but it's not the same. See my edit.

Comment: `functions of the form x^α are only defined for x>0` While it is true that functions of the form $f(x, \alpha)=x^\alpha$ are only defined when $\,x \gt 0\,$ for ***arbitrary*** $\,\alpha\,$, this is not the case here. For a given fixed $\,\alpha\,$ the domain can be the entire $\,\mathbb{R}\,$ e.g. for $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}\,$, or for fractional powers with odd denominator like $\,\alpha=\frac{1}{3}\,$.

Comment: I'm still going to restrict the definition to $\Bbb R^+$ just because negative bases can cause ambiguities. I did consider both cases, so hopefully everyone's happy

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in the  function $$f(x)=(x-2)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

This function is continuous and well defines on $(-\infty, \infty )$

It is symmetrical around the point $(2,0).$

The intercepts are $(0,-2^{1/3})$ and $(2,0)$

It is not differentiable at x=2 because its derivative is $ f'(x)=\frac{1}{3(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$

It is increasing  on  $(-\infty, \infty )$

It is one-to-one so it has an inverse function.

It is concave up for $ x<2$ and concave down for $x>2$